# Is there any way to do this without indexOf?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, indexing

I'm having trouble with

> Task 6: As corporate wants to add more and more flavors to their
> lineup, they've realized that they need to remove flavors based on
> flavor name,  as opposed to just arbitrarily removing the first or
> last flavor. Your task is to get an index by flavor name, and remove
> that single flavor from the array.
>
> Use the removeFlavorByName function below to do the following:
>
> ```
> 1. Receive an array
> 2. Receive a flavor as a string
> 3. Remove the received flavor from the received array
> 4. Return the resulting array that now contains one less flavor
> ```
>
> For example: running `removeFlavorByName(originalFlavors, "Rocky Road")` would return an array with the a length of 30
> because `Rocky Road` would have been removed.
>
> HINT: You can use `.splice()` for this

This is my code:

```
function removeFlavorByName(array, str){
  if (array.includes(str)) {
    let string = array.indexOf(str);
    array.splice(string, 1);
  }

  return array
}
```

Can Anyone Tell Me how to do this without using indexOf? I believe the testing software Lamda school is using wants us to use only the basic stuff because this fails their npm test thing even though it works.

Comment: You can use array.filter or the most basic stuff to do would be to create a new array without including `str`

Comment: Personally I would not do the includes step. I would just check for -1 before doing the splice. My guess is you were learning about loops and they wanted you to loop???

Comment: `indexOf` *is* basic stuff - I doubt they'd want you to use `splice` but not `indexOf`. Can you show us the test result/output of the failing tests please? Your code looks really fine (apart some potential for optimisation, and an edge case in the handling of `NaN`).

Comment: The instructions specifically say to "get an index by flavor name". It doesn't make sense that they would prohibit using `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

#### The simplest way to do this with with FILTER

If you use `.splice` then you must decide where to splice: to do that you need to know the result of `.indexOf`, whether you actually use the `.indexOf` function or not.

However if you are allowed to do it without `.splice`, then the easiest way is with the `.filter` higher-order function.

This acts on an array, and feeds in a function that decides for each element, whether the element should be kept or not.

```
function removeFlavorByName(array, str){
    return array.filter(item=>item!==str)
}
```

How this works is as follows:

> return a new array, constructed from the old array as follows:
> take the elements of the old array, and filter them using the following function:
> if the element does not equal str,
> include it in the new array, otherwise do not include it

Comment: I think the "HINT" suggests that this is not how they're expected to solve it.

Comment: Their instructions say **Remove the received flavor from the received array** which means to modify the array in place. `filter()` returns a new array.

Comment: Ah, I see this now in the updated question. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.indexOf is an old built in function. It’s the least complex way to perform this with splice. The Array.prototype.splice function takes an index and I believe it was built to work with .indexOf specifically.

> Your task is to get an index by flavor name, and remove that single flavor from the array.

That first part essentially describes how indexOf works. So unless they specifically told you not to use indexOf, you might be overthinking that part.